# How to use CSS in order to make a container float on the right side with prioritization for vertical height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create the following setup in CSS, but am having no luck doing so: https://gyazo.com/42e85e7bd7823839bf738eece8c3e588

I basically want to have a max height container of 300px, and then have this red box be empty space and have some metadata in the blue box float on the right side of this 300px container. My objective though is to make the blue container take up all of the vertical space and then expand horizontally as it needs more space. If there is very little content in the container then it will have a low width but still use all 300px of the height if possible. If there is more content (e.g. in the third example in the screenshot), then it expands horizontally until needed.

So in order it should:

1. Try to use all of the vertical space available to shove the content in the blue box (assuming you start off with 1px of width)
2. Expand the horizontal width of the blue are as it runs out of space for the content vertically (e.g. all 1px width is used, so expand to 2px, 3px, 4px...up until it has enough space to display the content). Meanwhile the vertical space is still always 300px.

What I currently have is this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="fakeBox">
      <h1>
        Garbage
      </h1>
      <p>
        I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS I hate CSS 
      </p>
      <button>
        Example Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but as you can see, it overflows and does not expand the blue section as it needs to.

Can someone who is experienced with this stuff point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: you are asking a lot for CSS. Unfortunately for you, it cannot work that way. Even with JS you will have a hard time implementing such thing .. an easy algorithm (1) fix the width to 1px (2) fill all the space (3) if all space covered OK, if not get back to (1) and try again [increase the width by 1px] (4) repeat until the content is inside

Comment: ^ this a naive implementation. A more clever one would be to have a step different from 1px based on your content but you will also need a lot of iteration and probably a back and forth to get the best value. Well it can be a good exercise but clearly out of the CSS scope

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of the blue box. No need to do anything else. Or am I getting you wrong?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="fakeBox">
      <h1>
        Garbage
      </h1>
      <p>
        I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS I love CSS 
      </p>
      <button>
        Example Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick response. The other problem I am having is that I want it to be greedy with the vertical space first. So I want it to try and use ALL of the vertical space available in the blue container first, and then start expanding horizontally only when all of the vertical space is gone. I will clarify this in my initial question.